# print python same std:cout

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want print in a console in a script of python, i not want use rospy.loginfo or warn. I want something like C ++ cout.
Any idea?

Edit 1:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Software License Agreement (BSD License)

import rospy
import roslib
import tf
import sys

import serial, string, math, time, calendar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('Compass', anonymous=True) 

    try:
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            rospy.logwarn("Angulo yaw: %.1f", z_axis_direction * orientation_rad / math.pi * 180.)
            print " Print "
            sys.stdout.write("stdout")
                rospy.loginfo("ros info")
    pass
```

Rospy log warn prints in a console but like a warning message with yellow color. Print and stdout not do anything. And finally rospy log info print in a /rosout topic.

Edit 1:
The launch

```
<!-- Compass nodo of Furuno PG-1000 -->
<launch>
       <node name="compass1" pkg="nodos_creados" type="FurunoCompassNode.py" respawn="true">
       </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216901/print-python-same-std:cout/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-09-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) on 2015-09-02**:
Are you launching the node using roslaunch? What does your launchfile look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really a bit off-topic, but what about `print(..)` or `sys.stdout.write(..)`?

---

Edit:

> ```
> <node name="compass1" pkg="nodos_creados" type="FurunoCompassNode.py" respawn="true" />
> ```

Try adding `output="screen"`. Without that, the stdout of your node will not end up on your console. Which is probably why you don't see any output when using `print(..)` or `sys.stdout.write(..)`.

See also [wiki/roslaunch/XML/node - Attributes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node):

> `output="log|screen"`(optional)

> If 'screen', stdout/stderr from the node will be sent to the screen. If 'log', the stdout/stderr output will be sent to a log file in $ROS_HOME/log, and stderr will continue to be sent to screen. The default is 'log'.

And for instance [How can I get my cout output on the console with roslaunch](http://answers.ros.org/question/9473/how-can-i-get-my-cout-output-on-the-console-with-roslaunch/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-09-02**:
That does not work! I do it and not print anything on the console, is for this that I ask this question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-09-02**:
Then you should've given us more information. Please update your original question (using the *edit* button/link) with an example (so Python source) of what you tried, what happens and what you think should happen.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-09-02**:
print definitely works. You're probably doing something in how you setup/run the node that redirects stdout.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2015-09-02**:
OK!! Thank you @gvdhoorn , I had not realized that.